General formula for the volume of a wedge given its six coordinates
Is there a formula for the volume of a wedge given the 6 coordinates $(x_i, y_i, z_i)$, where $i = 1 \ldots 6$.


In solid geometry, a wedge is a polyhedron defined by two triangles
and three trapezoid faces. A wedge has five faces, nine edges, and six
vertices. (from Wikipedia)

Unlike the wedges shown in Wikipedia, whose opposite triangles are coplanar etc, I am interested in we the general formula of the polydron. (Such geometrical objects appear in the finite element method and no assumptions can be made about the coplanarity of faces.)
This object is sometimes referred to as Pentahedron (prism) or Triangular prism in literature.
I've found a formula for the volume of a tetrahedron from its coordinates but not the volume of a wedge.

Please edit your question to say precisely what you mean by a wedge. Why is it difficult to determine its volume?

Please include a picture/diagram of this.

So we’re taking two triangles (in general non-congruent and in non-parallel planes) $ABC$ and $A’B’C’$ and joining $AA’$, $BB’$, and $CC’$ with line segments?

@TedShifrin exactly. Well put!

Why this this question relevant? "Such geometrical objects appear in the finite element method." with reference.

Your post mentions a formula for computing the volume of a tetrahedron given its coordinates.
Consider the labelling below. This wedge can be considered as the union of three disjoint tetrahedra, formed by the vertices $(A,D,E,F)$, $(A,C,F,B)$ and $(A,B,F,E)$. The volume of each of these can be computed and summed to give the wedge's volume.


Three tetrahedra glued in that arrangement form a 3-ball (verifiable by computing the homology or constructing the triangulation in relevant software).
The triangulation is purely topological, the vertices can be 'dragged' to meet the relevant vertices of a particular wedge. The only 'difference' is the addition of the edges $AF$, $AE$ and $BF$.

Thanks. I'm including a reference for posterity.
